# Download Google spreadsheet data into App Inventor to display it as table

Tags: android, google-sheets, app-inventor

I have got an app that posts a lot of barcode scanned in data on to a Google spreadsheet which stores the Scanned ID, ID, firstName, SecondName and Email Address. The  data is always being updated as new barcodes are being scanned in the google sheet. I would like to get this data unto date in a table form on the click of a button displaying on a different screen within the same app.

Currently I have tried so many different ways of doing this including downloading the file but having no luck getting it to open up and manually inserting the data which is not what it is supposed to do.

I do not really want to make use of fusion tables as i don't really understand how they work.

I have done this to download the CSV file

but when it run it I get a runtime error

[image]

Can someone give advice on the best way to do this.

UPDATE 2:

Since making the changes my coding blocks look like this:

I don't get the information in the form of a table and also the information on the next page is not complete and not even allowing me to scroll downwards.

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

UPDATE 3:

I have managed to make the page scrollable but still no html table working

UPDATE 4:

I have had the file uploaded as assets but still it does not work
I have now uploaded the results screenshot of Label1.Text when clicking on the download button

UPDATE 5:

I have made the changes but now the label just says trying to downloading and doesn't even display the table or the data from the CSV the web viewer is displaying just the html code.

Answer (score 1):

You get a **runtime error**, because you are downloading a file in csv format and in the `Web.GotFile` event you are assigning that csv file to an `image` component, which obviously is not possible.

Instead of downloading a file, download the **content of the csv file** instead!

To do that, set `Web.SaveResponse` to false, use the `Web.GotText` event to receive the response content, and then use [this solution](https://puravidaapps.com/table.php) to display the table in a `webviewer` component.

[image]

Edit: Concerning your problem with the asset `table.html`, [see my answer to your other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35091205/1545993).

Comment: I have managed to get the data from the spreadsheet to the app but its not in the green table format and also the data is not scrollable which does not allow me to see more records than the ones fitting on the screen.

Comment: You will have to upload the file *table.html* as asset into your app and the adjust the `HomeURL` as described in the mentioned example. Also you might want to provide a screenshot of your `Label1.Text` (the result you are getting from the `Web.GotText` event)

Comment: I have uploaded the latest results in (UPDATE 4) but i am still having the same problem. the coding blocks can be seen in (UPDATE 2)

Comment: as already said, use the *correct* `HomeURL`!!! Then set the `Webviewer.WebViewString` in the `Web.GotText` event and call `Webviewer.GoHome`, see updated answer.

Comment: I have made the changes but it seems to have made the problem worse i have attached the results in (UPDATE 5)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, why the source code will be displayed instead of the table... Does my example without modifications work for you? How do you test? Using the companion app? If yes, you should set the flag development to true. You might want to edit your question and keep only the relevant parts. Good luck!

Comment: I have also tried running your example and that also gives the same result of html displaying instead of the table. I test it on my phone (samsung galaxy s2) so directly put it on to the download folder and install it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101727/discussion-between-amit-and-taifun).