# App inventor displaying html code instead of dynamic table

Tags: android, html, google-sheets, samsung-mobile, app-inventor

I have an app that needs to collect data in a csv format from google sheets into app inventor also the html code is supposed to load the table to make the data downloaded more presentable.

My results in app screen:

[image]

Comment: Try one of the other App Inventor/HTML examples, for example [the coordinates example](https://puravidaapps.com/coordinates.php) to find out, if this is a device specific issue.

Comment: I have used most of your example to test it and the importCSV one does not work however the read text file example works perfectly fine when it is using a similar concept

Comment: both these examples are deprecated... what about the mentioned coordinates example? sorry, I do not have any idea, why this does not work for you... you said, you are using a Samsung device, which Android version? You might want to test using another device (not Samsung), which uses another Android version to find out, if it's a device specific issue...

Comment: I can't find the download link for the mentioned coordinates example. The android version is 4.1.2. I will have to try and find a different device to test it on.

Comment: I have just tested it using my friends motorola device and the same problem occurs in there as well so i think it might be a code block fault however the example one works great with the html table displaying really well.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your project, I found out, that the end-of-line characters of your asset `table.html` somehow disappeared.

And after uploading the correct asset `table.html` including the end-of-line characters, everything works fine again.